# How to count number of the same data in a database in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo, count

I am trying to count number of the e-mail addresses in a database that are same as the one acquired by a POST method. But it seems this code cannot count the number correctly, and returns a blank space instead. Is there something wrong in my PHP code? Thank you for taking your time.

```
<?php
  require_once('PHP/function.php');

  $mail = $_POST['email'];


  $sql = "select count(*) as num from `xxxx` where `mail` = '{$mail}' ;";
  $count = mysqlPDO($sql);
  $count = $count[0]["count(*)"];

  echo "number of the same email adress:\n".$count;
?>
```

`function.php` is below;

```
<?php
    function mysqlPDO($sql){

        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=aaaaa;host=localhost';

    try{
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn,'xxx','zzzzzzz');
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh -> query("SET NAMES utf8;");
        $stmt = $sth= $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array());
        $result=$sth->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        }catch (PDOException $e){
          $result = "error";
        }

        return $result;

    }

?>
```

Comment: Change `$count = $count[0]["count(*)"];` to `$count = $count[0]["num"];`

Comment: you already created an alias for `count(*) as num`, just access the index `num`

Comment: and what's the use of having it `->prepare()`d if you're just going to directly inject variables in `$sql`, its like using a crowbar to hammer a nail

Comment: thank you for your suggestions! I tried ' $count = $count[0]["num"];' to access the count but seems it does not work out well...

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($count);` after `$count = mysqlPDO($sql);` and tell us what you get. Thanks

Comment: @Erwin I got `int(6)`!

Comment: @Erwin I am a little confused. `int(6)` means the database has the same 6 data?

Comment: Actually, the `var_dump` should give you an `array` or `false`. Not an int.

Comment: @Erwin thank you for your comment! It seems like 6 doesnt mean how many of the same data it has...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the PDO method of doing things. But based on the research I've done after you execute the SELECT statement `$sth->fetchColumn();` should return the number of rows matching the $_POST email address.

```
$count = $sth->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: thank you for your comments! I tried that, but the error message says `Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on null in xxx.php on $count = $sth->rowCount();`

Comment: oops, I think I didn't put you code in a right way... How can I add your code in my code? thanks!

Comment: @Tak try replacing rowCount() with fetchColumn() I know it doesn't make sense for number of rows but according to another post I read rowCount() only returns rows that have been deleted. fetchColumn() should return number of rows in SELECT statment

Comment: thanks! hmm still does not work. I put `$count = $sth->fetchColumn();` just on the main php file (not function.php). I guess I should have put that at a different place.. where should I add it?

Comment: @Tak you should try putting the statement in function.php after you run the exec() function. does that work?